# How to read files depending on their file type

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I want to write a code that can get file from user and then read files depending on their filetype i.e. if it is a json file then it must read it as json file and if it is a pickle file then read it as pickle file. My code is as follows:

```
import os
filename = input("Enter File Name ")
fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)
if fileExtension==".json" :
  print 'This file is flac file %s' %files
 elif  fileExtension==".mp3":
   print 'This file is mp3 file %s' %files
 else:
   print 'Format is not valid'
```

I understand this concept but for this i have to write seperate `elif` for each file type. Is their any way that file is handled at once based on the file type entered by the user instead of writing code for each file type?

Comment: Also, this isn't python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write code for different files as each file must be read differently. so there is no option for that.

tip:- you can make functions to a specific file type and pass them that file. will help clean up your code

Comment: I thought their might be something built in for this purpose. Thanks for clearing.